# How to convert VBR OGG Opus audio to M4A ACC without quality loss?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion

I got some audio files in the OGG Opus format (~152kbit/s VBR, 48kHz sample rate) and I want to convert it to M4A ACC format without any quality loss.

I tried to use `ffmpeg -i myaudio.ogg -c:a aac -vn -b:a 152k myaudio.m4a`, but I doubt this will be truly lossless conversion, because it re-calculates the VBR. I tried to use `-qscale 0` instead of `-b:a 152k`, but it will attempt to convert to ~128kbit/s VBR, instead of fully preserving the input quality.

Is there even a way to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not possible

AAC is lossy, so it is not technically possible to convert to AAC without quality loss.

However, given enough bits you may not notice any quality loss.